# HTML/CSS - Styling for print, background wont show up?

Tags: html, css, printing, background

I'm having some trouble making a site, identical to viewing it in the browser, for print. It looks good, the only thing that got me stuck is that it refuses to display backgrounds. The images are fine though, it's just backgrounds. I haven't tried setting an image as a background, but that shouldn't be necessary anyways, right?

I'm applying the background to a DIV element, with hex colors, if that matters.

Is there any way around this? I searched for it but i didn't find anyone was having the same problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Some browsers may ignore the background when printing, to save ink.

Answer (score 5):

By default many browsers does not print background images and colours. You need to enable that in the print options. Chrome does not have that option but to make a WebKit browsers (Safari, Google Chrome) print the background image or colour you should add the following CSS style to the element:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for our internal supported browser list. Top respect.

Answer (score 3):

Background images being printed or not is not something you can force via CSS: it's a browser's setting and most (if not all) browsers default to the '*not*'.

Comment: Hmm, alright. Is there any workaround? I didn't set an image as a background, i just set a solid color, but i don't think that matters..

Comment: I think there is not (unless you ask nicely your visitors to change their browser settings). As a very general rule backgounds should be used for decorative elements and such; if your background includes informative content you might make it an image (I mean an IMG element) - this will be printed - and if necessary hide the text content with one of the many 'image replacement' techniques.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using two separate elements, for example a paragraph and an image, and then setting the z-index of the image lower than the z-index of the paragraph and then absolutely positioning the image behind your content. But I would recommend not having the background print. Otherwise you're messing with users' expectations and people will probably get annoyed.

Comment: I might give that a shot. I'm not setting a background for the entire page, i'm just setting it for a table header. I don't think they'll get annoyed by that. :)

Comment: Good call. Actually, it makes a lot of sense to display the background on a table header... hmm... I'll have to do some brainstorming and see if I can come up with a more efficient way to do that. Another thought, you could use an image in the table header that contains the text you want as well as the background. Just make sure you use the correct alt text if you use that approach.

Comment: The nice thing with a lot of browsers is that if you have white text on a black background, for example, the browser will change your text color to black when you print without the background.

Answer (score 1):

CSS: `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px gold;`

Works for all browsers and on table cells and rows.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question asked? They were asking about background images not printing. How does box-shadow relate to that *in any way whatsoever*?

Comment: @Andrew, this trick is just perfect: the box shadow becomes the background and then it is printed !

Comment: Hmmm, @Guillaume; I see that, now. The extra explanation edited in also helps. Thanks for correcting me!