# Text Background not applied while printing

Tags: html, css, printing, ckeditor

I changed the background color of a text, it works in side editor. But while printing background missing. How can I fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stylesheet for printing, background-color ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139593/stylesheet-for-printing-background-color-ignored)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using google chrome, it had an option can remove both backgrounds and images when printing that default value was enabled. Check out the print preview page and disable it.

Edit:
According to.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11296931/1040870
Another try is using CSS to let webkit browser print:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

It works on my testing; And will overwrite the option I mention before.

Answer (score -1):

Try the @media queries... @media print { **propeties** }

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/